# Split an audio file into 1 second chunks of audio tensors using tf.data.map?

Tags: python, tensorflow2.0, tensorflow-datasets

I'm trying to create a TensorFlow dataset using audio files of variable lengths. These files belong to a single 'noise' class and I already have the files with 1-second length for other classes. Here's what I have done:

```
import tensorflow as tf
from glob import glob

NUM_SAMPLES = 16000

#
# Other preprocessing functions here
#

def split_wav(file):
    wav = decode_audio(file=file, desired_samples=-1) # Returns tf.float32 tensor 
     # Slice 16000 length splits and drop remaining
    n = int(tf.size(wav) / NUM_SAMPLES)
    audio = wav[:(n * NUM_SAMPLES)] 
    x = tf.split(audio, num_or_size_splits=n)
    label = path_to_label(file)
    y = [label for _ in x]
    return x, y


@tf.function
def transform_fn(dataset: Dataset) -> Dataset:
    dataset = dataset.map(split_wav)
    # Dataset got kinda batched (on purpose) after split_wav i.e. splitting variable
    # length input tensors into multiples of 16000
    dataset = dataset.unbatch()
    dataset = dataset.map(to_mfccs)
    dataset = dataset.map(add_batch_dims)
    return dataset

# Load all classes starting with _ (noise class)
files = glob('data/v1/[_]*/**/*.wav', recursive=True)
ds = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(files)
ds.apply(transform_fn)
```

This, however, raises the following:

```
ValueError: Rank-0 tensors are not supported as the num_or_size_splits argument to split. Argument provided: Tensor("Cast:0", shape=(), dtype=int32)
```

So my problem becomes: How do I pass a 0 rank tensor as split_size in `tf.split(tensor_to_split, split_size_here)` function

If I load all the audio files, split them manually and create a dataset then that means running out of memory and freezing my system (my dataset is large). Is there any better way to do this than what I have done here?

Comment: Why do you ask about the 0 rank tensor specifically ?

Comment: The variable n in split wav function happens to be a tensor of rank 0 and that can't be used in tf.split

Comment: EDIT: in graph*

Answer (score 3):

It turns out you can't evaluate a tensor in a graph. Here's a solution to the problem using `tf.reshape` instead of `tf.split`:

```
NUM_SMAPLES = 16000

def split_wav(file):
    wav = decode_audio(file=file, desired_samples=-1) # Returns tf.float32 tensor 
     # Slice 16000 length splits and drop remaining
    n = int(tf.size(wav) / NUM_SAMPLES)
    audio = wav[:(n * NUM_SAMPLES)] 
    x = tf.reshape(tensor=audio, shape=(n, NUM_SAMPLES)) # Reshape along batch dim
    return x
```

Credit: A fellow Redditor on r/tensorflow